# Creating slippy map from large shapefiles?

Tags: qgis, wms, slippy, oruxmaps

I am trying to create a map of the UK based on a number of open data sources (Ordnance Survey Open Data, OSM, some CSV files etc).

My end goal is to create a map of the whole of the UK that I can view in OruxMaps or some other similar slippymap style offline client.

I am really struggling to work out the best way to do it though.

I have tried importing the data into QGIS, styling it and then using QGIS Server, but I can't figure out a good way of creating the slippy map from there.

I have tried TileMill, but it can't cope with the 2.5Gb contour .shp file.

I have looked around at various other things too, but just cannot work out the best way of doing this.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you looked at setting up [Geoserver](http://geoserver.org/) to style and serve the content? It should be able to cope with all the data sources, and you can then build the tile cache with the built in geowebcache (or possibly tilemill, I'm not sure if it can consume WMS or WFS data sources).

Comment: I had heard of GeoServer, but didn't realise that it could do that type of styling. With GeoWebCache, can you create actual tile "atlases". I got the impression that it was kind of like Squid Proxy for WMS...

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing something similar (topographic maps styled in QGIS and then exported to slippy maps for offline use).  The script runs from within QGIS and processes the map in (configurable-sized) subsets so if QGIS can display the source data you should be able to render it to tiles.

[Slippy map tile generator for QGIS](http://alephnull.net/software/gis/tile_writer.shtml)

Comment: do you have any code repo where to push some enhancement?

Comment: @LuigiPirelli Sorry for taking a while getting back to you, been pretty busy. I've set up a public repository at https://github.com/Alex-Kent/tile_writer The files there are slightly updated from what's on my website but there are no code changes (only documentation and comment changes)